# Adding points to a race circuit

Tags: python, interpolation, circuit

I have 2 arrays in Python with latitude and longitude coordinates. They correspond to coordinates of a circuit. A plot of it looks like this :
[Plot of the race](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyRhJ.png)

The fact is that I need more points on my circuit, and ideally I need all the points to be at the same distance from each other.

I suppose this has something to do with interpolation, because Python has no problem to link the points when I plot it, but I can't find an interpolation function for that.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You could add points in between pairs of points if the distance between the points of the pair is too big. Example in pseudo code:

```
points_array = a new empty array of points

p1, p2 = two successive points
distance_p1p2 = sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x)² + (p1.y - p2.y)²)

# Add p1 to the new array of points
points_array.push(p1)

if distance_p1p2 > threshold:  # threshold = 0.00005 for example, you can define it
    # Create an intermediate point in between p1 and p2
    intermediate_point.x = (p1.x + p2.x) / 2
    intermediate_point.y = (p1.y + p2.y) / 2
    
    # Add this intermediate point to the new array of points
    points_array.push(intermediate_point)

# Add p2 to the new array of points
points_array.push(p2)
```

These simple steps allow you to add a middle point between 2 points that are too for from each other. Starting from an empty array and looping between all your points, you'll get a new array with more points (or the same amount of points if the threshold is too big).

Then, you can iterate and do this algorithm as many times as you want.

I would like to point the fact that this is basic algorithm, nothing optimized. For example, you could analyze the distance between each pair of points and create `n` intermediate points instead of 1 at a time.